# Null condition check for expired cookies getting from Request. Cookies

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cookies

I tried the most of the things to do this. And i couldn't find the solution. I tried the following things

I have assigned the cookie value as the following,

```
   HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CKUserRole");
                cookie.Value = userRoleName;
```

I need to check the condition here in jquery

```
if('@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CKUserRole"].Value'!=null)
{
//But always it is executing and throw the error. 
}
```

Then i change the code into viewdata as the following in controller,

```
ViewBag.CKUserRole = userRoleName;
```

I am getting this in jquery like ,

```
  if ('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["IsSecurityCheck"]))' != null) {
```

This one is also executing and throwing an error. Kindly suggest me to do the null check.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this do something like this.

```
if('@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CKUserRole"]')
{
//will not throw an error. 
}
```

Comment: throwing "object reference not set to an object" error after use the above code also.

Comment: '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CKUserRole"]' check with this instead of this '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CKUserRole"].value'